# how to cut off power from usb device using arduino

Tags: arduino, usb, mosfet, switches

Seems like I can't restart USB modem in Linux, so I setup an arduino gig to emulate usb modem plug/unplug.

I have Arduino Uno R3 and several N-channel mosfet https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10213, and used the setup in http://bildr.org/2012/03/rfp30n06le-arduino/ for switching the ground wire of the usb modem on/off.

This works, for a while, then the usb hub started to have problem. I think I have to really emulate USB plug/unplug, that is, cutting off both the power wire and the data wire of the usb modem.

The problem is, while the USB power has +5V and ground, the data has D+ ~+2.5V and D- ~-2.5V, they doesn't have a common ground, to be used with the setup using N-channel mosfet.

What should I do? if I buy another arduino uno just for the data wire, I still have problem, the data ground is not the same with the arduino ground (I think N-Mosfet requires a common ground), I don't know if this will cause problem.

Do I need a DC voltage step-up component? or is there other solution.

I'm thinking how usb plug works, is first connect the power wire, wait some micro seconds then connect the data wire, with unplug the opposite.

Comment: Have you thought about using good old relays?

Comment: You should never open just the ground wire of a USB connection; this causes all kinds of problems, as you discovered. You should use a P-channel FET in the V_USB wire instead.

Comment: @arne is there a component you would recommend? I thought relay was to be used to switch off AC power :P

Comment: A relay is nothing more than an electromagnetically activated switch. A switch can be used for any kind of circuit (AC or DC) so long as it's rated for the voltage and current of the system. Keep in mind I would still recommend @Turbo J's answer. Use a PMOS on the USB power rail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> switching the ground wire of the usb modem on/off.

Bad choice. Use a P-channel MOSFET (like [IRLML6401](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irlml6401.pdf)) to switch the +5 Volt wire instead.

Cutting GND could make the data lines float near the 5 Volts power level, because there is usually some ESD protection on them. There may also be some return current on them. Both would cause malfunctions in USB hubs.

> how usb plug works, is first connect the power wire, wait some micro seconds

The reason behind this is to reduce the chance of ESD damage in the data lines - the power lines are much less likely damaged by ESD. You don't need to separate the data lines (and GND) at all if you just cut the power on the 5 volt line.

Comment: For P-ch MOSFET is there other component I'd need? For example for N-ch MOSFET, I have to add pull-down resistor to the gate.
I've searched local online arduino shops but they don't have P-ch MOSFET, they do have relays but not the solid state one.